# C++ use parameter of a constexpr function as constant for template

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

Since C++ does not allow template class with a value parameter template of "auto" type (you can `template<int N>`, or `template <EnumFoo E>`, but you cannot really match both), I wanted to write a wrapper for a type+value.

The real problem is, no one wants to write both value and its type, and I tried to write a function a bit similar with `make_unique`, except that creating a `std::unique` object, it was supposed to have a return type being the wrapper.

Here is what I wrote:

```
enum class E1
{
  First
};

enum class E2
{
  First
};

/*
 * Here, the goal is to be able to have a ClassTemplatedOnAnyValueNoMatterType
 * you can template on E1::First, or E2::First, and the template instances
 * are NOT the same one.
 * We need a wrapper (EnumValueWrapper).
*/
template <typename T>
struct ClassTemplatedOnAnyValueNoMatterType
{};

template <typename T, T Value>
struct EnumValueWrapper
{
  static const T value = Value;
};

/*
 * Since it's annoying to write EnumValueWrapper<E1, E1::First>, we'd like to
 * have a utility function that generates the EnumValueWrapper type.
*/
template <typename T>
// does NOT compile, t outside of function body
constexpr auto makeEnumValueWrapper(const T t) -> EnumValueWrapper<T, t>;

typedef ClassTemplatedOnAnyValueNoMatterType<decltype(makeEnumValueWrapper(E1::First))> MyClass;

int main()
{
  MyClass s;
}
```

This does not compile, and I'd like to know if there are any alternatives, using as few macros as possible (no `MACRO(E1, First)`, since I'd like to be able to use not only litterals, and would like to be able to use int type too).

Got any ideas to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wouldn't this work for your problem:

```
template <typename T>
struct Dummy
{
    template <T t>
    friend EnumValueWrapper<T, t> makeEnumValueWrapper();
};
template struct Dummy<E1>;
typedef ClassTemplatedOnAnyValueNoMatterType<decltype(makeEnumValueWrapper<E1::First>())> MyClass;
```

you still need the explicit instantiation of the Dummy on each of the relevant classes, but the typedef for MyClass is free of redundant type/value specification.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for a later iteration of C++.

Proposals to allow type parameters to depend on the type of value parameters have been proposed.  As yet, none have managed to pass muster.

If waiting doesn't sound like a good idea, dive into the standardization process and add it to C++ yourself.

Until then, continue to pass the type of your `template` constants into the `template`.

Comment: Good to know it's been proposed, do you mind putting a link so that me and other readers can access it easily?

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't like macros, but a very simple solution is:

```
#define WRAP_VALUE(...) EnumValueWrapper<decltype(__VA_ARGS__), (__VA_ARGS__)>

typedef ClassTemplatedOnAnyValueNoMatterType<WRAP_VALUE(E1::First)> MyClass;
```

I don't believe it's possible to do it without boilerplate without macros. My reasoning is that if you don't use a macro, you can only use your "value" expression once - either as a function argument, a template parameter, or as part of decltype. And neither alone is useful. If you use it as a function argument, you can't retrieve its value as a constant expression. You can't use it as a template parameter in the first place, since there is no way to declare a template parameter that will accept a value of arbitrary type - not without another template parameter representing that type. And finally, if you use it within decltype(), the value will be lost.

The macro is using `__VA_ARGS__` instead of a single argument so that you can use commas  within the expression. For example, when invoked as `WRAP_VALUE(std::is_same<float, bool>::value)`, the preprocessor would otherwise complain that the macro is called with two arguments.

Comment: I believe I can bare this small macro, especially it works on constants and integer literals (problems will arrive if I start to use parenthesis in an expression, but works on most cases for me). Thanks!